# splitting array into arrayList for every 6th value

Tags: java

I have this string array str[] which can be very long. I want to split it into arraylists or array with 6 values each, so:

```
str1[] = [str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5]]
str2[] = [str[6], str[7], str[8], str[9], str[10], str[11]]
```

And so on, how do i do this?

Comment: You need to show effort.  What code have you tried so far?

Comment: With a little bit of reflection, by reading some documentation, make some trials, fix bugs, and finally doing it, all by yourself.

Comment: just split the string using `string.split(",");`

Comment: @EisaAdil OP has `String[]`, not `String`. `split` is not right tool for this.

Comment: You'll need `index%6` to position your strings in the new mini arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a 2d array of strings to accomplish this.

```
str = ... // this is your array of strings

chunks = str.length / 6;
String[][] strs = new String[chunks][6];

for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        strs[i][j] = str[i*6 + j];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably actually better than my `index%6` plan. One thing I would say is that you'll get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` if `str`'s length isn't an exact multiple of 6

Comment: it will be, so that's not gonna be a problem

Comment: Yeah, I didn't check any edge cases here but this is the general framework you could use.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way, you can also use `System.arraycopy`, allowing you to not pre-specify the number of chunks or sub-arrays in advance. Just use an ArrayList of arrays as follows:

```
        ArrayList<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        int arraySize = 3;
        String[] first = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "D", "E", "F", "g", "h",
                "i", "J" };
        for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i+=arraySize) {
            String[] foo = new String[arraySize];
            if (i + arraySize <= first.length) {
                System.arraycopy(first, i, foo, 0, arraySize);
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(first, i, foo, 0, first.length - i);
            }

           arrays.add(foo);
        }
```